# Прерывание звука в ffplay и ALSA buffer xrun

Tags: аудио, ffmpeg, alsa

День добрый!
Пишу захват видео и звука средствами ffmpeg с последующей передачей через rtsp. На другой стороне воспроизвожу через:
ffplay -rtsp_flags listen -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://127.0.0.1:5010/live.sdp.
В итоге видео воспроизводится отлично, практически без задержки, звук синхронизирован, но постоянно заикается и вываливается **на передающем конце**:

```
*Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':  
  Duration: N/A, start: 820.460825, bitrate: 147456 kb/s  
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 640x480, 147456 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc  
Input #0, alsa, from 'plughw:0,0':  
  Duration: N/A, start: 1489589531.994862, bitrate: 1536 kb/s  
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1536 kb/s  
[libx264 @ 0x61d480] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX  
[libx264 @ 0x61d480] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.1  
[libx264 @ 0x61d480] 264 - core 142 r2389 956c8d8 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html 

-options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0
 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=4 lookahead_threads=4 sliced_threads=1 slices=4 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0
 bluray_compat=0   constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=12 keyint_min=1 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0crf=20.0 qcomp=0.60
 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4   ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0  
    Output #0, rtsp, to 'rtsp://127.0.0.1:5010/live.sdp':  
        Stream #0:0: Unknown: none (libx264)  
        Stream #0:1: Unknown: none (aac)  
    [rtsp @ 0x61b700] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.  
    [rtsp @ 0x61b700] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.  
    [alsa @ 0x608b40] ALSA buffer xrun.   
    [alsa @ 0x608b40] ALSA buffer xrun.  
    [alsa @ 0x608b40] ALSA buffer xrun.  
    [alsa @ 0x608b40] ALSA buffer xrun.  
    [alsa @ 0x608b40] ALSA buffer xrun.  
    [alsa @ 0x608b40] ALSA buffer xrun.*
```

**А на принимающем:**

```
*ffplay version 3.2.2 Copyright (c) 2003-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.7 (Debian 4.7.2-5)  
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local --enable-shared --enable-ffplay --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --disable-nvenc  
  libavutil      55. 34.100 / 55. 34.100  
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101  
  libavformat    57. 56.100 / 57. 56.100  
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100  
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100  
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100  
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100  
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100  
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://127.0.0.1:5010/live.sdp':   0B f=0/0  
  Metadata:  
    title           : No Name  
  Duration: N/A, start: -0.048005, bitrate: N/A  
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p(progressive), 800x600, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc  
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp  
ALSA lib pcm.c:7339:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred  0B f=1/1  
ALSA lib pcm.c:7339:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred  0B f=1/1  
ALSA lib pcm.c:7339:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred  0B f=1/1  
ALSA lib pcm.c:7339:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred  0B f=1/1  
ALSA lib pcm.c:7339:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred  0B f=1/1  
ALSA lib pcm.c:7339:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred  0B f=1/1  
ALSA lib pcm.c:7339:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred  0B f=1/1  
ALSA lib pcm.c:7339:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred  0B f=1/1  
ALSA lib pcm.c:7339:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred  0B f=1/1  
ALSA lib pcm.c:7339:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred  0B f=1/1  
   4.12 A-V:  0.142 fd=   1 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=1/1*
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема?

И снова здравствуйте!
Разделил передачу аудио и видео разными потоками по RTP ....

```
.......
pthread_create(video_thread, NULL, video_thread_streaming, (void*)&video_info);
            pthread_join(*video_thread, NULL);
            encode_video = video_info.write_result;
.......
pthread_create(audio_thread, NULL, audio_thread_streaming, (void*)&audio_info);
            pthread_join(*audio_thread, NULL);
            encode_audio = audio_info.write_result;
......
```

на принимающей стороне:

```
ffplay -protocol_whitelist file,udp,rtp video.sdp | ffplay -protocol_whitelist file,udp,rtp audio.sdp
```

результаты те же... (((( ... сыпится "ALSA buffer xrun"!!!

Заметил очень интересную вещь:
Если освещение в помещении хорошее, эта ошибка не появляется и передача и воспроизведение происходит великолепно в обоих случаях (rtsp & rtp) с задержкой где-то порядка 1 секунды. Если же света недостаточно, то сыпится "ALSA buffer xrun", причем при чтении пакета из аудио потока (контекста):

```
static int decode_audio_frame(AVFrame **frame,
                              InputStream *input_audio_st,
                              int *data_present)
{
    AVPacket input_packet;
    int error;
    init_packet(&input_packet);
 ......

    av_read_frame(input_audio_st->inp_fctx, &input_packet) - **вот здесь сыпится ALSA**
  .......

    avcodec_decode_audio4(input_audio_st->st->codec, *frame,
                                       data_present, &input_packet)
  .......
    return 0;
}
```

Есть какие-нибудь идеи по этому поводу???

И вот еще что. Если уменьшаю количество кадров исходящего видео до 15, ошибка перестает сыпаться. А в коде это соответственно timebase = (1, 15) OutputCodecContext. Никак не могу сообразить как все это связано.....

Answer (score 1):

Сделай [буффера (`-rtbufsize`)](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Format-stream-specifiers-1) побольше на стороне читателя из ALSA или порегулирую [размер очереди (`-thread_queue_size`)](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#toc-Advanced-options) для пакетов (начни с 1024) - это увеличит задержку, но может оказаться неплохим демпфером.

Звук RealTime и для него задержки, которые вносит сеть очень критичны. Ещё можно попробовать RT-ядро. В Ubuntu-based это ядра linux-image-lowlatency, а во всяких Manjaro - linux-rt-manjaro.

Но, вообще, пока эта проблема общего решения [не имеет](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/615): FFmpeg внутри достаточно последовательный и синхронный. К примеру [тут](https://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2013-March/014090.html) одно из решений проблемы: запись звука и видео двумя независимыми процессами. Но для RTSP это не вариант.

Comment: добавлял эти опции:    av_dict_set(&optionsDict, "rtbufsize", "15000000", 0);  av_dict_set(&optionsDict, "thread_queue_size", "2048", 0); и затем avformat_open_input(&input_st->inp_fctx, filename, fmt, &optionsDict) при чтении звука, результат тот-же.

Answer (score 0):

Я столкнулся с такой же проблемой - при изменении освещенности сыпется звук. Положим, что увеличение буфера лишь маскирует положение (ffmpeg -loglevel verbose перестает сыпать xrun), но заикания и/или полное исчезновение звука в стриме это не решает.
Когда я пытался заменить ffmpeg на vlc, для его корректной работы (vlc) требовалось установить pulseaudio. vlc на orangePiZero2 не вывез в плане транскодирования и был удален. Так вот, после устнановки пульса бага с освещением перестала беспокоить совсем, а после запуска ffmpeg через конфиг rtsp-simple-server ушел и небольшой, но неприятный audiodrift.